# Solving a non-linear equation in python: the answer is the same as initial guess

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, equation-solving

So I have this complicated equation which I need to solve. I think that finally `x` should be of order 1E22. But the problem with this code is that it crashes my entire system. Is there a fix? I tried `scipy.optimize.root` but it doesn't really solve anything at this order of magnitude (it gives final answer as initial guess without any iteration).

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
import mpmath
import scipy
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import sqrt,exp

x = Symbol('x',positive=True)

cs = 507.643E-12
esi = 1.05E-10 
q = 1.6E-19
T = 300
k = 1.381E-23
ni = 1.45E16

print(solve(exp(x/((2*cs/(esi*q))**2)) - ((x/ni)**(esi*k*T)),x))

def func(N):
    return (math.exp(N/math.pow(2*cs/(esi*q),2)) - math.pow(N/ni,(esi*k*T)))

n_initial_guess = 1E21
n_solution = fsolve(func, n_initial_guess)

print ("The solution is n = %f" % n_solution)
print ("at which the value of the expression is %f" % func(n_solution))
print(scipy.optimize.root(func, 1E22,tol=1E-10))
```

Neither of the scipy functions work. The sympy function crashes my laptop. Would Matlab be ideal for this?

Comment: The problem is here `print(solve(exp(x/((2*cs/(esi*q))**2)) - ((x/ni)**(esi*k*T)),x))`. this is not the optimal way to get the result. it will basically consume a huge chunk of memory making your laptop to crash. try using a different technique to solve the equation rather than using sympy solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Numeric solution with SciPy

The problem that SciPy has with this equation is the [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). You are raising N to the tiny power `esi*k*T` which makes it very near 1; in floating point arithmetics, it becomes exactly 1.  Similarly, the part coming from the exponential becomes 1. Then the two parts are subtracting, leaving 0 - equation appears to be already solved. You could have seen this happening by printing `func(1E21)` -- it returns 0.

The way to deal with the loss of significance is to rewrite the equation, from the original form

```
exp(x/((2*cs/(esi*q))**2)) == (x/ni)**(esi*k*T)
```

by raising both sides to the power `1/(esi*k*T)`:

```
exp(x*esi*q**2/(2*cs*k*T)**2)) == x/ni
```

So `func` becomes

```
def func(N):
    return np.exp(N*esi*q**2/(k*T*(2*cs)**2)) - (N/ni)
```

(It's is advisable to use NumPy functions with SciPy solvers.) That said, the solvers, for example `root(func, 1E10)`, will report being unable to converge to a solution.

#### Symbolic solution with SymPy

SymPy is for solving equations analytically. It does not care for a bunch of floating point numbers. Give it a symbolic equation instead:

```
x, a, b, c = symbols('x, a, b, c', positive=True)
sol = solve(exp(x/a) - (x/b)**c, x)[0]
```

The solution is obtained as `-c*LambertW(-a/(b*c))/a`.  Then it can be evaluated:

```
cs = 507.643E-12
esi = 1.05E-10 
q = 1.6E-19
T = 300
k = 1.381E-23
ni = 1.45E16

print(sol.evalf(subs={a: (2*cs/(esi*q))**2, b: ni, c: esi*k*T}))
```

Which prints `-21301663061.0653 - 4649834682.69762*I` confirming what one would already expect from the failure of convergence with SciPy: there are no real solutions of the equation.